# "The model item passed into the dictionary is of type "

Tags: asp.net, .net, model-view-controller

'The model item passed into the dictionary is of type 'CambroKatman.WebUI.Areas.Raporlama.Models.RaporModel', but this dictionary requires a model item of type 'CambroKatman.WebUI.Models.LayoutModel'.'

I got this  error on my MVC project. Can anyone help me to fix  it ?

-----This is my controller.

```
using CambroKatman.WebUI.Areas.Raporlama.Models;

    public ActionResult RaporOzetTablolar(RaporModel gmodel)
    {

        var model = new RaporModel()
            {
                ErrorCodeDefinitonlar = DbHelper.ErrorCodeOzel(Convert.ToInt32(department.Id)),
                LangShortDef = gmodel.LangShortDef,
                departmentSecimi = gmodel.departmentSecimi,
                tarihSecimi = gmodel.tarihSecimi
            };
       
        Session["rmodel"] = model;
        return this.PartialView("~/Areas/Raporlama/Views/Raporlama/OzetTablolar.cshtml", model);
    }
}
```

-----Layout.cshtml

```
@using CambroKatman.WebUI.Models


@{
    Layout = null;
    var mmodel = (LayoutModel)ViewBag.LayoutModel;
    //var mmodel = new LayoutModel();
}

<body class="@bodyClass">
    <!-- BEGIN HEADER -->
    @Html.Partial("~/Views/Shared/_HeaderUst.cshtml", mmodel)  !!!!!!I GOT THE ERROR THIS LINE!!!!!! 
    <div class="clearfix"> </div>
```

-----headerust.cshtml

```
@model CambroKatman.WebUI.Models.LayoutModel

<div class="page-header navbar navbar-fixed-top">
    <!-- BEGIN HEADER INNER -->
    <div class="page-header-inner ">
        <!-- BEGIN LOGO -->
        <div class="page-logo">
            <a href="@Url.Action("Index","Home")">

                <img src="@Url.Content("~/assets/Resimler/logo.png")" alt="logo" class="logo-default img-responsive" style="max-width: 125px;" />
            </a>

            <div class="menu-toggler sidebar-toggler">
                <!-- DOC: Remove the above "hide" to enable the sidebar toggler button on header -->
            </div>
        </div>
        <!-- END LOGO -->
        <!-- BEGIN RESPONSIVE MENU TOGGLER -->
        <a href="javascript:;" class="menu-toggler responsive-toggler" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> </a>

        <div class="page-top">

            <div class="top-menu">

                <ul class="nav navbar-nav pull-right">

                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-user">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                            @Html.Raw(Model.DilPaketi.First(a => a.Id == Model.LangShortDef).Tanim) <span class="fa fa-flag-o"></span>



                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-default">
                            @{



                                foreach (var item in Model.DilPaketi)
                                {
                                    string iclass = "fa fa-flag-o";

                                    if (item.Id == Model.LangShortDef)
                                    {
                                        iclass += "fa fa-flag";
                                    }
                                    <li>
                                        <a href="@Url.Action("LangChange", "Home", new { id = item.Id, @returnUrl = Request.RawUrl, @Area = "" })">
                                            <i class="@iclass"></i> @item.Tanim
                                        </a>
                                    </li>
                                }
                            }


                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <li class="separator hide"> </li>

                    <li class="dropdown dropdown-user dropdown-dark">
                        <a href="javascript:;" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown" data-close-others="true">
                            <span class="username username-hide-on-mobile"> @Model.User.Name </span>

                            @*@if (Model.Kullanici.FileName == null)
                            {
                                <img alt="" class="img-circle" src="@Url.Content("~/assets/Resimler/avatar.jpg")" />
                            }
                            else
                            {
                                <img alt="" class="img-circle" src="@Url.Content(Model.Kullanici.FileName)" />
                            }*@


                        </a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-default">
                            @*<li>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("ProfilBilgi", "Kisisel")">
                                    <i class="icon-user"></i> Kişisel Bilgileriniz
                                </a>
                            </li>


                            <li class="divider"> </li>
                            *@
                            <li>
                                <a href="@Url.Action("LogOut", "User", new { @Area = "" })">
                                    <i class="icon-key"></i> ÇIKIŞ YAP
                                </a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                    <!-- END USER LOGIN DROPDOWN -->

                </ul>
            </div>
            <!-- END TOP NAVIGATION MENU -->
        </div>
        <!-- END PAGE TOP -->
    </div>
    <!-- END HEADER INNER -->
</div>
```

-----LayoutModel

```
namespace CambroKatman.WebUI.Models
{
    using CambroKatman.DAL.Concrete.EntityFramework.Data;
    using CambroKatman.Entities;

    public class LayoutModel
    {
        public LayoutModel()
        {
            DilPaketi = new List<DropItem>()
                            {
                                new DropItem(){Tanim = "TÜRKÇE", Id = "tr"},
                                new DropItem(){Tanim = "ENGLISH", Id = "en"},
                            };
            KullaniciLinkleri = new List<BaseUserLink>();
            User = new KALITEPera_User();
            UserHeaderItemListe = new List<UserHeaderItem>();
        }
        public KALITEPera_User User { get; set; }

        public string LangShortDef { get; set; }

        public List<BaseUserLink> KullaniciLinkleri { get; set; }

        public List<DropItem> DilPaketi { get; set; }

        public List<UserHeaderItem> UserHeaderItemListe { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserHeaderItem
    {
        public UserHeaderItem()
        {
            UserLinkList = new List<BaseUserLink>();
            LinkGrupTanim = new KALITEPera_WebAdminLinkGrupTanim();
        }

        public KALITEPera_WebAdminLinkGrupTanim LinkGrupTanim { get; set; }

        public List<BaseUserLink> UserLinkList { get; set; }
    }

    public class UserYetkiSorguItem
    {
        public int RoleTanimId { get; set; }

        public int LinkGrupTanimId { get; set; }
        public string LinkGrupTanimAdi { get; set; }
        public string LinkGrupTanimAdiEng { get; set; }
        public string IclassName { get; set; }
        public string AreaName { get; set; }
        public string ControllerName { get; set; }
        public string ActionName { get; set; }
        public string LinkTanimAdi { get; set; }

        public string LinkTanimAdiEng { get; set; }
        public int DetayLinkDurumu { get; set; }
     

    }
}
```

------RaporModel.cs

```
namespace CambroKatman.WebUI.Areas.Raporlama.Models
{
    using System.Security.AccessControl;
    using System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates;
    using System.Threading;

    using CambroKatman.BLL.Helpers;
    using CambroKatman.Entities;
    public class RaporModel
    {
        public RaporModel()
        {

            RaporClassDefinitionHeaderlar = new List<RaporClassDefinitionHeader>();
            RaporClassDynamicDefinitionHeaderlar = new List<RaporClassDynamicDefinitionHeader>();
            ErrorCodeDefinitonlar = new List<ErrorCodeDefiniton>();
            DropItemList = new List<DropItem>();
            DropDateList = new List<DropItem>();
            departmentSecimi = "-1";
            tarihSecimi = "0";
        }


        public List<RaporClassDefinitionHeader> RaporClassDefinitionHeaderlar { get; set; }
        public List<RaporClassDynamicDefinitionHeader> RaporClassDynamicDefinitionHeaderlar { get; set; }
        public List<ErrorCodeDefiniton> ErrorCodeDefinitonlar { get; set; }
        public string LangShortDef { get; set; }
        public List<DropItem> DropItemList { get; set; }

        public string departmentSecimi { get; set; }
        
        public List<DropItem> DropDateList { get; set; }
        public string tarihSecimi { get; set; }
        public string basTarihi { get; set; }
        public string bitTarihi { get; set; }
        public List<DropItem> DilPaketi { get; set; }

    }

    public class RaporClassDefinitionProdOrderNo
    {
        public string ProdOrderNo { get; set; }

    }

    public class RaporClassDefinitionHeader
    {
        public RaporClassDefinitionHeader()
        {
            RaporClassDefinitionItemlar = new List<RaporClassDefinitionItem>();

        }
        public DateTime ProductDate { get; set; }
        public DateTime CheckDate { get; set; }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string ProdOrderNo { get; set; }
        public string ProductionOrderNo { get; set; }
        public string ItemNo { get; set; }
        public string FormNo { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public string TestId { get; set; }
        public string TestDetailId { get; set; }
        public string WorkCenter { get; set; }
        public string Operator { get; set; }
        public string VardiyaA { get; set; }
        public string Olcu { get; set; }
        public string Desen { get; set; }
        public string UrunCinsi { get; set; }
        public decimal Karantina { get; set; }
        public decimal Kurtarilan { get; set; }
        public string Musteri { get; set; }
        public int Result { get; set; }
        public string Vardiya { get; set; }
        public string PresAdi { get; set; }
        public string PresId { get; set; }
        public decimal Kalite1 { get; set; }
        public decimal Kalite2 { get; set; }
        public decimal HataOrani { get; set; }
        public List<RaporClassDefinitionItem> RaporClassDefinitionItemlar { get; set; }
        public decimal SumResult { get; set; }

    }

    public class RaporClassDefinitionItem
    {
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string FormNo { get; set; }

        public string ProdOrderNo { get; set; }

        // üstler key

        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

        public int Result { get; set; }

        public string PresId { get; set; }

        public string PresAdi { get; set; }
    }

    public class RaporClassDynamicDefinitionHeader
    {
        public RaporClassDynamicDefinitionHeader()
        {

            RaporClassDynamicDefinitionItemlar = new List<RaporClassDynamicDefinitionItem>();

        }
        public string Department { get; set; }
        public string Sonuc { get; set; }
        public Dictionary<string, string> ErrorColumns { get; set; }
        public List<RaporClassDynamicDefinitionItem> RaporClassDynamicDefinitionItemlar { get; set; }

    }
    public class RaporClassDynamicDefinitionItem
    {
        public string ErrorCode { get; set; }

        public int Result { get; set; }

    }
    
}
```

I have tried to change my model's content.
I have tried to change @using models on my model codes.